# Call popup composable function inside onclick of Button in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Hi i want to show popup when something happens . I have this popup:

```
@Composable
fun popup(message:String,height:Dp,width:Dp,icon:String=""){
    Column() {
        val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
        val dialogWidth = width/(1.3F)
        val dialogHeight = height/2

        if (openDialog.value) {
            Dialog(onDismissRequest = { openDialog.value = false }) {
                // Draw a rectangle shape with rounded corners inside the dialog
                Box(
                    Modifier
                        .size(dialogWidth, dialogHeight)
                        .background(Color.White)){
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding()) {
                        Text(text = message)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Button(onClick = {
            openDialog.value=!openDialog.value
        }) {

        }
    }
}
```

But i am trying to call him inside onclick Button event :

```
Button(modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 6.dp, end = 6.dp),
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Azul99),
                    onClick = {
                             if (vm.validateCredentials()=="ok"){
                                 vm.createUser()
                             }else{
                                 popup(vm.validateCredentials(),200.dp,200.dp,"fill")
                             }
                    },
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(percent = 28)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Registrarme",
                        modifier= Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        style= TextStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold),
                        color= Color.White,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
                }
```

and Android Studio says: "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function" How can i call the popup ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store showPopUp boolean as state and show popUp by that state;

```
var showPopUp by remember { mutableStateOf(false)} // -> STATE
Button(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(start = 6.dp, end = 6.dp),
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Azul99),
    onClick = {
        if (vm.validateCredentials()=="ok"){
            vm.createUser()
        }else{
            showPopUp = !showPopUp // -> CHANGE IN HERE
        }
    },
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(percent = 28)
) {
    Text(
        text = "Registrarme",
        modifier= Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        style= TextStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold),
        color= Color.White,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )
}
if(showPopUp){
    popup(vm.validateCredentials(),200.dp,200.dp,"fill") // -> SHOW HERE
}
```

Change